# Why was my flag in this question declined?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging, vote-to-close, declined-flags

[How do I break down and plan a personal programming project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163375/how-do-i-start-a-personal-programming-project)

At a glance, the **title** put the question in danger of being closed as 'Off-Topic'. But further than that, the grammar is poor, and it's unclear what the OP is asking.

I flagged this question for immediate closure, but a moderator declined the flag because he thought it was of sufficient quality.

Comment: I didn't handle the flag but I'd like to point out that in general there's little point in flagging when you already can vote to close, unless the question is extremely poor or in any other way in urgent need of a moderator's attention (spam/offensive/etc). I've pinged the moderator who handled the flag so they can explain their reasoning, but I wouldn't be surprised if your flag was seen as noisy, since you can vote to close and don't really need us to help you with it.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't handle this flag, but since I'm hanging around anyway...

> I flagged this question for immediate closure

Actually, you used this flag:

[image: the "very low quality" flag description]

...That's the description for the "very low quality" flag. Clearly, it's intended for questions that are little more than *festering boils* - skip closing and editing, go straight to deletion.

> But further than that, the grammar is poor, and it's unclear what the OP is asking.

Yeah, but the grammar is easy enough to fix, and by the time you flagged someone had already asked for clarification and gotten a response. Heck, he even went on to post a pretty solid answer, which doesn't exactly scream "delete this disease before it kills us all!" to me.

So I went and edited it, cleaned up the grammar a bit, and added the clarifying comment to the question proper. It could probably use some additional editing, but for now I think it'll do.

Comment: Perhaps "delete this disease before it kills us all!" should be the title of the VLQ flag...